# animating search bar with jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

firstly here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/r1pfwwe4/1/)

I'm trying to animate a search form, right now it starts from left to right, I want it to start from right to left. I also want to add a nice easing to the animation.

HTML Code:

```
<form role="form" class="search-form-2">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <div class="search-toggle" style="display:none">
        <input type="text" class="search-form" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" size="25">
    </div>
</form>
```

JS code:

```
$("i.fa.fa-search").click(function () {
    $(".search-toggle").animate({width: 'toggle'});;
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `.search-toggle` inside a `div` with `id="container"`. Add CSS property `float: right` to `.search-toggle` and your search box will animate from right to left.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1pfwwe4/7/)

#### HTML:

```
<form role="form" class="search-form-2"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="search-toggle" style="display:none">
      <input type="text" class="search-form" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" size="25" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

#### CSS:

```
i.fa {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 10000;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
input.search-form {
    padding: 10px;
}
#container {
    width: 300px;
}
.search-toggle {
    float: right;
}
```